# Key Names With @ Symbol

Tags: rest, powershell, hashtable

I'm doing some REST API work in PowerShell, and some of the keys I need to pass to my REST API contain at symbols (`@`). Alternatively, some of the keys that are returned from my REST API contain at symbols (`@`).

Is there anyway to escape this character and use the value as a literal for the key?

Example:

```
Context "Get Details By Machine Name" {
    Mock Invoke-RestMethod {
        return @{
            links = @{}
            content = @{
                @type           : CatalogResource
                id              : e5c83e8b-31df-4573-b14e-246ded62ba53
                iconId          : edd4f05a-5c59-485c-9d5b-d0280d7a6432
                resourceTypeRef : @{id=Infrastructure.Virtual; label=Virtual Machine}
            }
            metadata = @{
                size          = 20
                totalElements = 1
                totalPages    = 1
                number        = 1
                offset        = 0
            }
        }
    }
```

I need `@type` to be the key of the hashtable.

Comment: Have you tried quotes ? `$ht = @{"@type" = "value"}` is a valid HashTable definition, access with `$ht["@type"]`

Comment: ahahahaha... I swear I tried that.. It's so obvious and yet I looked forever for the solution. Even resorted to asking SO. Thank you Mathias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a key name start with `@` is no problem if your key names are in quotes:

```
PS C:\> @'
>> {
>>   "@foo" : 42
>> }
>> '@ | ConvertFrom-Json | Format-Table -AutoSize
>>

@foo
----
  42
```

Same if you define a hashtable in PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> $ht = @{ '@foo' = 42 }
PS C:\> $ht

Name                           Value
----                           -----
@foo                           42
```